# Проблема с выводом json массива в html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть массив в json формате, пока он в коде, все работает. Если выношу его в отдельный json-файл и в коде вызываю его в переменную, то вывод в html не работает.

```
{
  id: 0,
  title: "root - not displayed",
  children: [{
    id: 0,
    title: "Россия",
    children: [{
      id: 0,
      title: "Архангельская обл",
      children: [{
        id: 111,
        title: "Архангельск",
      }, {
        id: 112,
        title: "Северодвинск",
      }]
    }, {
      id: 12,
      title: "Москва",
    }]
  }, {
    id: 0,
    title: "Украина",
    children: [{
      id: 21,
      title: "Киев",
    }, {
      id: 22,
      title: "Одесса",
    }]
  }, {
    id: 0,
    title: "Белоруссия",
    children: [{
      id: 31,
      title: "Минск",
    }, {
      id: 32,
      title: "Гродно",
    }]
  }]
}
```

так получаю json в переменную

```
var tree = $.get('cityTreeExample.json', function (data) { tree = data;});
```

вывожу в html массив так

```
function addCityTree(parentUL, branch) {
  for (var key in branch.children) {
    var item = branch.children[key];
    $item = $('<li>', {
      id: "item" + item.id,
      class: 'list-tree__sub-item'
    });
    if (item.id==0)
    {
      $item.append($('<div>', {
        class: 'toogle-accordion',
        text: item.title
      }));
    }
    else {
      $item.append($('<input>', {
        type: "checkbox",
        id: item.id,
        value: item.title
      }));
      $item.append($('<label>', {
        for: item.id,
        text: item.title,
      }));
      $item.wrapInner($('<div>', {
        class: 'checkbox'
      }));
    }
    parentUL.append($item);
    if (item.children) {
      var $ul = $('<ul>', { 
        class: 'list-tree__sub-list'
      }
      ).appendTo($item);
      $item.append();
      addCityTree($ul, item);
    }
  }
}
//call function, which builds tree from json
addCityTree($('.js-city-tree'), tree);
  $(':checkbox').each(function () {
    $(this).find(':checkbox');
    var matchingId = $(this).attr('id');
    ($(this).attr('checked'))
      $('input[id*=' + matchingId +']').each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).prop('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
      });
  });
  $('.toogle-accordion').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
  });
  // add span tag to label
  $('.list-tree__sub-item label').prepend('<span></span>');
```

при `console.log(tree);` получаю в консоли 
[image: вывод переменной tree в консоль]

Comment: "вывод в html не работает" - что это значит? 1. Вы используете переменную `json` до того, как выполнится функция `function (data) { json = data;}`. и/или 2. Вы ошибочно считаете, что переменная  `tree` содержит Ваши данные.

Comment: json = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Посмотрите в консоль разработчика в браузере. Может там есть ошибки.

Comment: почитайте, что возвращает `$.get`: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Может вам лучше getJSON использовать вместо get.

Comment: это каша, а не код, полный код с html давайте.

Comment: в html пишем `<ul class=".js-city-tree"></ul>`, думал это итак понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решена, в getJSON кладем функцию обработки массива таким образом и все работает.

```
$.getJSON("cityTreeNon.json", function(tree) {
function addCityTreeCheckbox(parentUL, branch) {
  for (var key in branch.children) {
    var item = branch.children[key];
    $item = $('<li>', {
      id: "item" + item.id,
      class: 'list-tree__sub-item'
    });
    if (item.id==0)
    {
      $item.append($('<div>', {
        class: 'toogle-accordion',
        text: item.title
      }));
    }
    else {
      $item.append($('<input>', {
        type: "checkbox",
        id: item.id,
        value: item.title
      }));
      $item.append($('<label>', {
        for: item.id,
        text: item.title
      }));
      $item.append($('<span>'));
      $item.wrapInner($('<div>', {
        class: 'checkbox'
      }));
    }
    parentUL.append($item);
    if (item.children) {
      var $ul = $('<ul>', { 
        class: 'list-tree__sub-list'
      }
      ).appendTo($item);
      $item.append();
      addCityTreeCheckbox($ul, item);
    }
  }
}
//call function, which builds tree from json
addCityTreeCheckbox($('.js-city-tree'), tree);
$('.toogle-accordion-workactivity').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('li').children('ul').toggle();
});
// add span tag to label
$('.list-tree__sub-item label').prepend('<span></span>');
});
```

P.S был небольшой косяк со структурой json файла, переписал на такое (дело не только в кавычках)

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "title": "root - non displayed",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Russia",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "title": "Vol obl",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 111,
              "title": "Vologda"
            },
            {
              "id": 222,
              "title": "Cherep"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно заключить названия свойств объектов в кавычки

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "title": "root - not displayed",
  "children": [{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Россия",
    "children": [{
...
```

Comment: добавление кавычек не помогает (

Comment: Это такой подход к программированию - называется "культ грузовых самолетов". "А давайте попробуем кавычки добавить, вдруг поможет?"

Comment: Кавычки в любом случае нужны, если хотите придерживаться стандарта.

Comment: Вот, если интересно, спецификация - http://www.json.org/

Comment: да проблема то не в кавычках, если этот массив присвоить в переменную tree, то все работает, строится дерево без проблем, дело в том как правильно присвоить массив из внешнего файла?

Comment: @GeorgeSkripak, это все потому, что очень многие путают JSON, и литеральную нотацию при объявлении объектов в яваскрипте - они весьма сильно отличаются, JSON накладывает довольно много ограничений на то, что и как можно писать

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь:

```
var tree = $.get('cityTreeExample.json', function (data) { json = data;});
```

У вас ответ от сервера помещается в переменную `json`, а затем вы почему то используете переменную `tree`.

Кроме того вместо $.get, используйте [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), который для этого и предназначен, чтобы не парсить текст ответа.

Comment: исправил на `var tree = $.getJSON('cityTreeExample.json', function (data) { tree = data;});` но изменений никаких

Comment: Может вы не ждете пока ответ придет, а сразу пытаетесь использовать tree?

Comment: а как подождать пока ответ придет?

Comment: Вызывайте `addCityTree($('.js-city-tree'), tree);` в `$.getJSON('cityTreeExample.json', function (data) {` ... `});`

Comment: такой вариант уже пробовал, не работает, я  еще не могу понять почему когда сам массив присваиваю в переменную и потом эту переменную вызываю, все работает, а когда получаю из внешнего файла, то не работает

Comment: @GeorgeSkripak, потому что присвоение в переменную - синхронная операция, а загрузка с помощью `ajax` - асинхронная. Весь код нужно поместить либо в `success` коллбэк, либо в коллбэк переданный методу `then` возвращенного объекта

Comment: @Grundy да, проблема была именно в этом, переложил всю функцию в $get и все норм зарабтало (там правда небольшой косяк еще с самим json был)

Answer (score -1):

```
$.getJSON('cityTreeExample.json', function (json) { 
console.log(json);
});
```